# Gitlab + Ansible Deploy/administrate multiple cluster

Tags: git, ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to have some advises on how to organise my work in Git/Ansible.

Lets say I have a Gitlab project, with Ansible roles/playbooks inside.
I am using gitlab-ci jobs with ansible to deploy my cluster (Elastic, Kubernetes, whatever).

**How would you organise your project when you have dozens of clusters ?**

On folder per cluster, Ansible style ? But in this case one modification would apply to all clusters, and you don't want to upgrade/patch all clusters at once.

One branch per cluster ? And rebase from master on each branch when you want to update ?

Or one project per cluster, forking from the main project ?

One more question : **How would you authenticate your runner for Ansible to work ?** 
Putting ssh key in secret variable in Gitlab, and setting it inside docker runner ?
But anyone with dev access to the project could print the variable in a job and get the ssh key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A separate repository for each project ( k8s , elastic , ... ) per cluster
- A separate branch for each environment , test , prod
- Use proteted Secret variables in protected banches
- Protect all the branches so that no one can push directly , and create a merge request instead
- Accpet changes from developers as merge request , so that you review the changes , what they are doing before merging , so that you dont allow anyone to change the ci files to echo secrets
- You can also use the file locking feature in EE version  , but the protected branches approach is better
- You can also get secrets from hashicorp vault instead , on the runner

Comment: Thx for the answer. 
But with this solution, you are "forced' tu upgrade all your cluster together.
Maybe with a versionning, like galaxy ? And setting the specific version for each deploy job per cluster in my gitlab-ci.
What happens if you have multiple prod clusters and don't want to upgrade them all at the same time ?

Comment: @Victor as I said , make separate repos per cluster , and branches per environment , i made it more explicit now

Comment: I read too fast and stayed at a repo per project.. 
So one "master" project, and then forks for each cluster, and one branch per environment. I'll try this. Thx.
(and if you know some blogs/posts I could read about this, tell me !)

Comment: @Victor too busy at the job to write blog posts , just drop me an email just in case: ijazahmad722@gmail.com